# how to access event as well as value passed to function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how do i access event and value passed to function at a time
here is what i have tried

```
   <ul className="list" data-testid="lists">
              {options.map((option, i) => (
                <li
                  role="button"
                  tabIndex="0"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelected(option);
                    setOpen(false);
                  }}
                  className={state.cursor === i ? "activeList" : "list-item"}
                  onKeyDown={ handleEnter(option) }
                >
                  {option}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
```

```
  const handleEnter = (option, e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      setSelected(option)
    }
  };
```

what i want to do is when enter pressed want to update the state with value of option
but not able to do so
what should i do

Answer (score 2):

The event object is passed into the `onXXX` function.

If you want to pass it from the `onKeyDown` function to the `handleEnter` function then you must do so explicitly.

You also have to pass a **function** to `onKeyDown` in the first place, not `undefined` which is the return value of the function you are calling.

Use `useCallback` to stop the function being recreated on every render.

```
const onKeyDown = useCallback(
    (event) => handleEnter(option, event),
   [option, handleEnter]
);
```

and

```
onKeyDown={ onKeyDown }
```

Do note, however, that [`keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and we have better alternatives for it now.

Comment: thanks for the answer ... i have never used useCallback hook so it is giving error on option field

Comment: Oh, just saw that `option` is defined in the `map` callback. Do `map((option, i) => (<ANewComponent option={option} />))` and then you can `useCallback` in the new component.

Comment: i am using it in same component....

Comment: I can see that. That is why I recommended creating a new component.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the property like

```
onKeyDown={(e)=> handleEnter(option, e)}
```

it will bind your events in your handleEnter function.
I hope it will work for you. Thanks.

Comment: trie but not working

Comment: its actually not triggering handleEnter function

Comment: i tried with your code. you can check it in code sendbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dirac-2gc5s?file=/src/App.js 
it's working for me. you can also check console. Thanks

Comment: yes its working on ur side i dont knw whats wrong with my code